# 3 Kids - Probability of exactly 1 boy?

Tags: probability

How do I calculate the probability of getting exactly 1 boy if there are 3 babies born and the gender is determined at random?

Comment: How would you approach this/what have you tried?

Comment: I have multiplied 1/2 by 1/2 by 1/2. But in the answer key, it says the answer is 3/8.

Comment: Have you learnt the binomial distribution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2^3 = 8$ possible variations on birth. There are 3 chances that there is exactly one boy (BGG,GBG and GGB).

This gives you $3/8$

**Adition:** The 3 chances are calculated as $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

For your example $n=$ number of children and $k=$ number of boys.

Comment: How can I write that formally (say I was in a quiz)?

Comment: I can give you the exact notation later, I'm mobile right now. Probably someone elde will in the mean time.

Answer (score 2):

Write it exactly as each answer was written.

Answer (score 1):

If 3 babies are born, the possible outcomes are $2^3$

You want 1 baby out of the 3 to be male.

There're 3 possible outcomes:

(male, female female)

(female, male, female)

(female, female, male)

The probability is:

$p = 3/8$

Comment: How can I write that formally (say I was in a quiz)?

Comment: Using the classical definition of probability.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's do it from fundamentals.

If the boy is the eldest, viz. $B-G-G$, the probability would be $\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac12 =\dfrac18$,

but the boy could be at any of the $3$ places in the age sequence,

so $Pr = \dfrac38$

Answer (score 1):

Your comments say you're looking for a formula, perhaps to use on an exam. You don't need one. The explanations in the other answers should please any teacher. If you want a formula for more births than three, ...

You seem comfortable with the fact that there are $2^n$ possible gender arrangements when there are $n$ babies. (That's 8 when $n=3$.) If you're interested in just one boy, he can be born in any one of the $n$ places (the rest girls) so the probability is $n/2^n$.

If you want to know about the probability of $k$ boys in $n$ births you'll have to work harder. Look up Pascal's Triangle. You can start at wikipedia.